# Guava: Iterables.frequency(Iterable<T>, Predicate<T>)

Tags: java, guava

Is there really no method that determines the number of elements that satisfy a Predicate in an Iterable?
Was I right to do this:

```
return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(iterable, predicate)).size()
```

If so, what is the reason that there is no method

```
Iterable.frequency(Iterable<T>, Predicate<T>)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This may be easier:

```
return Iterables.size(Iterables.filter(iterable, predicate));
```

It avoids the allocation of all that array memory.

Comment: That's nicer. Internally it creates a counter and iterates through the filtered elements once.

Comment: Yes, it's better - but beware, if the Iterable refers to a somewhat dynamic "collection" (like a database table), you get an unreliable value in general. The "size" may be different each time you call `filter`. It's just a snapshot.

Comment: Sure, but how can any other solution avoid that? In general, if the collection is changing, the best you can hope for is a value that was correct and some point in time between the beginning and end of your call.

In some cases, you don't even get that - imagine a list which is concurrently modified, going through the following states:

A,B,C -> B,C -> B,C,D

The list never has size 4, but you might count four elements during iteration since you can see both A and D, if the concurrent modification occurs at the right moment.

Answer (score 4):

When the iterable is a collection, you could say

```
return Collections2.filter(collection, predicate).size();
```

There hasn't been much demand for an Iterable.frequency(iterable, predicate) method.

Answer (score 3):

This filter method does not create a collection. It creates a new Iterable with a new iterator and the filtering is done `on demand`, like when you actually iterate over the Iterable.

So yes, the guava framework *could* have a `frequency(Iterable, Predicate)` method, but this method would have to create the iterator internally just to get the number of iteration steps. And throw it away afterwards. And if your iterator works on dynamic collections (like database tables), the frequency "size" and the filter "size" may even be different.

If you need both (iterator *and* size), take the iterable, feed it in a suitable collection (freeze) and use the collections `size()` method. This guarantees a true size value for the (frozen) collection based on the filtered Iterable.

Comment: I think it was voted down, because that's what I did in the initial code, froze the Collection that results from applying the filter right now and the used the size() method on that one.
The original question resulted from the fact that there is a method Iterables.frequency(Iterable<T>, Object o) which counts elements that are equals() to o.